# MySql User Defined Variable

Tags: sql, mysql

How to use the user defined variable in a way that the value of the variable is reused in the subsequent query in mysql?

Comment: would this be inside a stored procedure?

Comment: no . i dont want it in stored prodcure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it:

```
SELECT  @r := 1

---
  1

SELECT  @r := @r + 1

---
  2
```